# What is one method I can use to play an mp3 when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, button, methods, mp3

Let me clarify. I am creating a soundboard (android application) for a class of mine and I used this method 30 times, one for each button/mp3

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class pageOneSounds extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pageonesounds);

final MediaPlayer pg1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);

Button playSound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound1Button);

playSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    pg1.start();

    }
});
```

So this method works well, but I am going to have 30 buttons with a scroll view on this layout. I was wondering if there is a method I could use that would allow me to have just one method and not have to copy and paste that .setOnClickListener 30 times. Let me know if I am making sense or not. Really new to java and android I don't really know what I'm doing/might not understand you.

Comment: You have require different sound as per button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xml file do this for each button:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/sound1Button"
  android:onClick="buttonClick"
  ... />
<Button android:id="@+id/sound2Button"
  android:onClick="buttonClick"
  ... />
<Button android:id="@+id/sound3Button"
  android:onClick="buttonClick"
  ... />
etc
```

And then in your pageOneSounds activity, do this:

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.sound1Button:
    // do what u want here for button 1
    break;
    case R.id.sound2Button:
    // do what u want here for button 2
    break;
    case R.id.sound3Button:
    // do what u want here for button 3
    break;
    // etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding on what exactly is going on here? I understand that you are telling each button to use the same method (buttonClick), but what is the method doing? What does case mean? what about break? If there are very broad questions, don't feel obligated to explain them to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @frosty I think you should look at Java programming first. Or even C if you have no programming background. switch, case, breaks are all keywords in Java (and other languages).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Some python and html background, but that's it. I just recently jumped into android apps so I am making a soundboard and learning on the way. Thanks. @harikris

Comment: @frosty Happy learning. The best resource for Android is the developer.android.com and for Java, i use Head First series.

Comment: thanks. One more thing; is the method you gave me more 'clean' or better than what I was doing before (posting the same method 30 times in the .java)?

Comment: @frosty yeah. from maintenance perspective, my suggestion is better. Mentioning onClick method in xml helps big time to in this case. Would you mind accepting my answer if you feel it's the right answer? Click on the Tick button to the left of my answer to accept it.

Comment: @karikris yeah I was going to. I cant get the code to work; does your code go inside the onCreate method or after it separately?

Comment: No, this is a separate method. Outside onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

make your class `implements OnClickListener`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
    {
        break;
    }
    case R.id.button2:
    {
        finish();
    }
           // define your working of button 
    }

}
```

dont forget to set `button1.setOnClickListener(this)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to save your `OnClickListener` to a variable so that you can simply pass it to all of your `setOnClickListener()` calls? This is possible by creating a variable for it like you would for any other type.

```
View.OnClickListener playSoundListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        pg1.start();
    }
};
```

Then pass it to `setOnClickListener()` like so:

```
playSound1.setOnClickListener(playSoundListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `OnClickListener` then use either **switch case or write** the mp3 play method of yours in `onClick()` **(if you dont have any other function keys)**

```
public class pageOneSounds extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    final MediaPlayer pg1;
    Button playSound1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pageonesounds);
        pg1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        playSound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound1Button);
        playSound1.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pg1.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method which will return an `Object` of MediaPlayer`. And on button click you can start your playing your sound.

```
public static MediaPlayer (Context context,int Idofmediaplayer) {
    MediaPlayer pg1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, Idofmediaplayer);
    return pg1;
}
```

Use `Switch case` or `if else` loop in `OnClickListener` method

```
MediaPlayer m = MediaPlayer (pageOneSounds.this, R.raw.sound1);
m.start();
```